# Extjs menu in frame, overflow

Tags: html, extjs, menu, frame

I've to rewrite an existing web application and port it to extjs components.
This is a bigger application and I have to do it in steps, I can't rewrite the whole application at once, the implementation of MVC will come later. At the moment the application has two frames, left frame with navigation menu
and links with href & target starting actions in main, right frame.

As first step I have to replace the self written navigation menu with extjs solution.
My problem is, the menu is quite big and has a lot of submenus and left frame is rather thin. As effect the menus are rendered partially under the right frame or shift outside the window on the left.

This screenshot shows the first problem:
[image]

This screenshot shows the second problem:
[image]

My question: is there a possibility to render the menus wider then left frame (over the frame)? Perhaps some layout container below the menu could be useful?
I would like to avoid the shift to the left and the cover through the main frame on the right.

Regards,
Annie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a possibility to utilize a ExtJS menu in narrow frame, but the tree component (Ext.tree.Panel) fits quite good and is a nice replacement. It looks like left navigation on the sencha api page. The question is closed for me.
Regads, Anie